# Смена цвета Polygon в Google maps API при генерации страницы

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

На карте будет нарисовано больше сотни фигур типа Polygon (многоугольников).

Вызов фигур будет хранится в файле, а координаты в БД. На каждой из страниц сайта будет показываться карта со всеми объектами, но нужно выделить именно тот объект, на страницу которого зашли. Вопрос, как это сделать?

Пусть это будет маркер, или другой цвет, не важно. Главное выделение объекта в зависимости от URL.

Пример вызова фигуры и её координат:

```
var buildingCoords1 = [ 

new google.maps.LatLng(46.391727,30.745642),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391867,30.745679),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391926,30.745819),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391778,30.746135),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391845,30.746457),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391767,30.746532),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391668,30.746543),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391623,30.746543),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391553,30.746232),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391364,30.746151),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391320,30.746157),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391312,30.746006),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391338,30.745878),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391594,30.745926),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.391723,30.745642)

];

// Construct the polygon1
var buildingObject1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: buildingCoords1,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#cf0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
buildingObject1.setMap(map);
```

[Ссылка на песочницу](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreyTsapko/3ysjdqpp/6/)

Comment: Ну пусть в базе вместе с координаторами хранится некий ид, который потом указывается в урле. Не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, проблема решена.

Перед buildingObject1.setMap(map); // Генерация карты

Добавил вот эту функцию.

```
// Change color for selected url

  function urlcheck () {
   if (window.location.href === 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/') {
    return buildingObject1.setOptions({ strokeColor: "#ff4d0f", fillColor: "#ff4d0f"});

   } else {
    return buildingObject1.setOptions({ strokeColor: "#ff4d0f"}) 
   }
 };

 urlcheck ();
```